# Regex to replace period after uppercase letter

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regex expression that will work for C#.Net in order to replace any period after any uppercase letter with a blank space like so `""`.

Example: `A. B.C.` to `A BC`

I've tried this: `s/([A-Z])\./$1/g`  but it only works for JavaScript, it has no effect in C#.

Comment: *any uppercase letter* - do you need to support all uppercase letters, or just ASCII?

Comment: Only uppercase letters. The answer that was provided worked just fine.

Comment: What stribizhev meant: do you expect letters like Ó À Ê Æ or just the plain 26-letter alphabet?

Comment: No, only the plain 26-letter alphabet.

Comment: What about etc sign? Like `A B C...`

Comment: No, the etc sign is not what I was aiming for or replacing.

Comment: Btw if you want to exclude them you can add negative lookahead . `([A-Z])\.(?!\.)`

Comment: Thank you for the additional tips. Might use them if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following RegExp: **`[A-Z]\.`**

Here is how you use it in C#:

```
string s = "A.basd.qweF.";    
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"([A-Z])\.", "$1");
```

Note that there is a capture group which is used for replacement.

Here is the [working IDEOne demo](http://ideone.com/zm3Q5Z).

Comment: I would use a verbatim string literal for regex declaration. "Backslash hell" is better avoided.

Comment: @stribizhev I have updated the answer in accordance with your recommendation :)